# How to print Armstrong numbers from 1 to 1000 in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I was doing code and error is showing.
Here's my code:

```
#/bin/bash
len=0
for (( start=1;start<=100;start++ ))              
do
        
    cl_no=$start                     
    while [ $cl_no -gt 0 ]
    do        
        cl_no=$( expr $cl_no / 10 ) 
        len=$(( $len + 1 ))
    done                                                                                               
    cln=$start
    mul=1
    sum=0
    while [ $cln -gt 0 ]
    do
        ldo=$( expr $cln % 10 )
        cln=$( expr $cln / 10 )
        for (( j=1;j<=$len;j++ ))
        do
        done
        sum=`expr $sum + $mul`   
        mul=1
    done
    if [ $sum -eq $start ]
    then
        echo $start
    fi
done
```

Any output is showing like this:

```
.../file/f1 $ bash print_arm_.sh                 
    1
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 1341068619663964900808: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 2417851639229258349412353: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 4710128697246244834921603690: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 302231454904207049490432: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 45474735088646414094775208677: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 2887378820390246558661986823962624: integer expression expected
    print_arm_.sh: line 55: [: 107006904423598033356356335569309873639: integer expression expected
    ^Z
    [9]+  Stopped                 bash print_arm_.sh
.../file/f1 $
```

It was showing continuously but I have presssed `ctrl+Z`.
I tried to solve but I don't know what's the error, can you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
i=100
while [ $i -lt 1000 ]
do
    x=$i
    sum=0
    r=0
    n=0
    
    while [ $x -gt 0 ]
    do
        r=`expr $x % 10`
        n=`expr $r \* $r \* $r`
        sum=`expr $sum + $n`
        x=`expr $x / 10`
    done
    if [ $sum -eq $i ]
    then
        echo $sum
    fi
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?